# Call a static method of a static class using reflection

Tags: c#, reflection

i trying to call a static method like this :

```
Assembly myAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(filePath);
Type Mytype = myAssembly.GetType("MyClass");
string returnedValue = Mytype.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(null, null).ToString();
MessageBox.Show(returnedValue);
```

but i get this error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
internal static class MyClass
{
internal static string MyMethod(int param1)
{
return "HI"
}
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem, regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to pass correct `BindingFlags` so your method can be found:

```
var methodInfo = typeof(MyClass).GetMethod("MyMethod", 
                                           BindingFlags.Static |
                                           BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

Then you need to pass correct parameters to the `Invoke` function:

```
methodInfo.Invoke(null, new object [] {1})
```